# Filter design for AD620

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, filter, analysis

*Hello everyone*
I have made an load sensing circuit using an  instrumentation amplifier AD620.
The sensor I have used is a typical load cell which is powered using +-5volt power supply. 
The Power supply i am using is Net35b meanwell power supply.(snippet from the datasheet)
 [image]

**QUESTION**
Do i need to design a filter for output stability? If yes how should i do it ??.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What is your stability spec needed?

Comment: @TonyStewart sorry sir , i don't know much about the technical terms ,I tried it myself but got confused ...I just want the output to not fluctuate or fluctuate less....Thank you !!

Comment: This is not your first question, so I would like to leave a comment. The title should not be all in capital. You do not need to address everyone and say hello in your questions, neither to say thanks. If someone or something was helpful, upvote their answer/comment.

Comment: @BenceKaulics  i will work on the title for sure , about hello and thank you ..well extremely experienced are helping out for free..its good to be grateful ..but i will kkeep that in mind ..Thank you

Comment: -1 Because you say you'll work on the title, but an hour later it's still in all caps.

Comment: @ThePhoton i literally had 7 points now i am down to 5 ... i deserved it anyways !

Comment: Whether you need to improve stability (or output ripple) depends on what maximum ripple your application can tolerate, and what is the ripple of the circuit you already designed. Since you've told us neither of those things, there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: In principle the power supply ripple becomes a common mode input to the in-amp, and so it should be strongly attenuated at the in-amp output. In practice, nothing's perfect, so give us more details about your problem and we might be able to give useful advice.

Comment: @ThePhoton This is my project  its a simple circuit to get output from a strain guage type pressure sensor : [link] http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/260389/ad620-pot-assembly-alternative-filter

Answer (score 1):

Your power supply generates ripple and this

- affects the IAmp directly but also
- affects the bridge sensor on the input (when imbalanced).

By how much the bridge gets imbalanced (under maximum load) only you know but, if you have a figure then you need to assume that this ripple produces a real signal that is amplified by the gain of the IAmp (if it is capable).

So, if full scale on your bridge is +5% on one limb and -5% on the other then you can calculate the differential voltage that is due to power supply noise/ripple. When the bridge is perfectly balanced, both inputs receive a potted-down version of the same ripple voltage and you need to then use the CMR (common mode rejection) figure for the IAmp to determine how large the ripple signal becomes on the output.

For rejection via the power rail it is simpler. See these graphs in the DS: -

[image]

The top graph is for the positive power rail. It is quite feasible that the "ripple" due to the switching frequency of the power supply might easily be at 100 kHz, so for an IAmp gain of 100, the PSR (referred to the input or RTI) is about ~70 dB. This means that with a gain of 100 (40 dB) the power ripple voltage of ~100 mVp-p is seen at a level of 40-70 dB at the output = 3.2 mVp-p. For the negative rail it will be a little higher at about 10 mVp-p.

Clearly if the switching frequency of the power supply were only 10 kHz then the artefacts on the output would be 20 dB lower.

Whether you choose to filter those artefacts after the amplifier or try and remove them from the rails is up to you but, as far as I'm concerned, I'd want that noise off the rails because it affects three mechanisms and let me remind you: -

1. Direct power supply rejection by the IAmp
2. Common mode rejection becauese that noise gets onto the inputs
3. Differential noise as the bridge gets imbalanced.

Comment: Thank you !! it took me 15 minutes to understand the concept and even then i don't know if what i think is right... sorry  i have never worked on this before ..The key points i got out of it were that i can design filter for this circuit but its better to attenuate noise at rails itself ..is there a way ? i am using decoupling capacitors for all ic's or should i change the smps as whole ...?

Comment: are there any good books that i can read for noise calculation and attenuation ?

Comment: Series inductance followed by a parallel capacitance to 0 volts makes a pretty decent filter but you have  to make the natural resonant frequency significantly lower than the ripple due to the power supply switching circuit. I don't read these sort of books any more and that's a real problem because what you want is seasoned engineers to recommend books but those guys haven't needed to read them in years.

Comment: thank you, i have used 100uf and 10 uf capacitors parallel at supply also 0.01uf capacitors as decoupling capacitors on each ic  what should be the series inductance  ? can we guess ?

Comment: 100 uF is not needed but 10uF and 10nF ceramic is good. Resonant frequency when using 10uH will be 15.9 kHz and likely to be significantly lower than the switching frequency but don't choose an inductor with a self resonant frequency lower than 10 Mhz else other problems may arise. Did noise reduce?

Comment: Yes noise reduced substatially when i just plugged in the POT assembly to Ref pin also caacitors seem to be doing good ..works great !